# How to remove the text from the table at the end of displaying table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not really sure how to quote this question, but I'm making a clone of Reddit in Ruby on Rails.

On the index page I am displaying all of the posts I have in the table "Posts". But when I display them all, at the end of the last post a text shows up which is wrapped in square brackets and contains all of the information from the table. I just want to know how to remove this text.

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shlrh.png)

This is the code used to display the post:

```
 <%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <small class="mb-2"><strong><%= link_to "s\\" + post.sub.name, sub_path(post.sub) %></strong> Posted by <%= link_to "u\\" + post.user.username, profile_path(post.user.username) %> <%= time_ago_in_words post.created_at %> ago</small>
    <h4><%= link_to post.title, sub_post_path(post.sub, post) %></h4>
    <p><%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [ :index, :show ]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show]
  before_action :auth_subscriber, only: [:new]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @sub = Sub.find(params[:sub_id])
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new post_values
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.sub_id = params[:sub_id]

    if @post.save
      redirect_to subs_path(@post.sub_id)
    else
      @sub = Sub.find(params[:sub_id])
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def auth_subscriber
    unless Subscription.where(sub_id: params[:sub_id], user_id: current_user.id).any?
      redirect_to root_path, flash: { danger: "You are not authorized to view this page" }
    end
  end

  def post_values
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <small class="mb-2"><strong><%= link_to "s\\" + post.sub.name, sub_path(post.sub) %></strong> Posted by <%= link_to "u\\" + post.user.username, profile_path(post.user.username) %> <%= time_ago_in_words post.created_at %> ago</small>
    <h4><%= link_to post.title, sub_post_path(post.sub, post) %></h4>
    <p><%= truncate post.body, length: 200 %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In ERB `<%=` is used to output the result of an expression to the buffer. `#each` in Ruby returns `self` so what you're seeing on the page is the result of implicitly calling `#to_s` on an array.

`#each` is always used for its side effects and not its return value. In the case of an ERB template each iteration writes to the buffer.

This can be somewhat hard to grasp but remeber that any plaintext in a template is written directly to the buffer - using `each` just does it n number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<%= @posts.each do |post| %>` for `<% @posts.each do |post| %>`, note the missing '=' in the second snippet.

When you include the '=' the output of `.each` is printed in the HTML, in this case the array of posts.